# Meaning of X month on X month AR inflation rate

Tags: inflation

Does 6m6m AR inflation rate mean the average of 6m price index, over the average of previous non-overlapping 6m price index, then x 2 to annualize?

E.g. if the CPI index is 101,102,...112 over 12 months, then 6m6m AR is {[(107+108+109+110+111+112)/6] / [(101+102+103+104+105+106)/6] -1} * 2 = [(109.5 / 103.5) - 1] * 2 = 11.6%?

Comment: What is "6m6m AR"? Please explain your abbreviations (or better, don't use abbreviations).

Comment: Thank you. That's the question acutally. For example it appeared here: https://twitter.com/fwred/status/1458429614364282880